# Temp view in stored procedure is valid only on first UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure that creates a temporary view and then perform multiple updates based on this temp view.
The problem is that this temporary view is not valid after the first UPDATE command (error is "Invalid object name").

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MySP]
    @passedParam VARCHAR(32)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH MyTempView AS
    (
        SELECT [myTable1].[Id]
        FROM [dbo].[myTable1] LEFT JOIN [dbo].[myTable2] ON [myTable1].Id = [myTable2].[DeviceId]
        WHERE 
        --all kind of conditions    
    )

    --The temp view is valid here
    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Ready] = 0, [myTable1].[Reason] = NULL
    WHERE
    [myTable1].[Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM MyTempView)

    --The temp view is NO LONGER VALID from this point
    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 1.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 2.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 3.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 4.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

END
```

how can that be solved ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: CTE is not a "temp view". _"that creates a temporary table"_ - there is no temp table creation code in your sp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Temp view will be invalid because scope of cte is limited to first update statement. So you insert results into temp table. And use it down in procedure where ever you want.

```
 USE [MyDB]
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MySP]
        @passedParam VARCHAR(32)
    AS
    BEGIN
       if object_id('tempdb..#t1') is not null
        drop table #t1
            SELECT [myTable1].[Id] into #t1
            FROM [dbo].[myTable1] LEFT JOIN [dbo].[myTable2] ON [myTable1].Id = [myTable2].[DeviceId]
            WHERE 


    --The temp view is valid here
    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Ready] = 0, [myTable1].[Reason] = NULL
    WHERE
    [myTable1].[Id] IN (SELECT [Id] FROM #t1)

    --The temp view is NO LONGER VALID from this point
    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 1.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 2.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 3.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

    UPDATE [dbo].[myTable1]
    SET [myTable1].[Reason] = CONCAT([myTable1].[Reason],'Reason 4.')
    WHERE
    --all kind of conditions

    END
```

Answer (score 0):

A *[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)* (CTE) created with `WITH name` precedes the one command it is part of:

```
with name
  ... implement CTE
update ...
```

It has no bearing on any further commands in the batch.

I think you're naming is confusing you:

1. `MyTempView` is not a view
2. `MyTempView` is not a temporary (would have a `#` prefix on its name)
3. Tables and view definitions (temporary or not) are not defined with `with`.

It is not clear what you are trying to achieve with a CTE here so not easy to suggest what would be a better approach.